# Drawing shapes in background TextView

Tags: android

I,m trying to paint circle in background of my textView. It should by a small object in up/left corner.

```
    temporar = new TextView(cxt);
    OvalShape oval = new OvalShape();
    //oval.resize(10, 10);
    qualitySignalDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(oval);
    qualitySignalDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
    qualitySignalDrawable.setBounds(2,2,10,10);

    signalQualityText.setGravity(Gravity.CLIP_HORIZONTAL);
    temporar.setBackgroundDrawable(qualitySignalDrawable);
    temporar.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
```

I tried set difrents gravity and size and Bounds but id allways stretch shape to container size. I'm missing something?